# Did the Jedi ever find out why Dooku turned to the Dark Side?

Tags: star-wars, jedi, the-phantom-menace, attack-of-the-clones, darth-tyranus

The Jedi knew Dooku was one of the Jedi Masters who are one of the "The Lost Twenty". When he left the Jedi Order due to that he was (as explain in [this answer from null](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/72357/70135)):

> Dooku was convinced that the Republic needed to be destroyed and rebuilt in order to fix its problems. Dooku felt this was needed because the Senate was ineffectual and the Jedi Council was unwilling to unleash the full power of the Force (i.e. use the dark side) to fix the Republic's problems (unlike the Sith). Dooku was convinced that he could rebuild the Republic by working with Palpatine (he did not yet know Palpatine was a Sith Lord and had developed a political friendship with him) and the Sith. Moreover, he felt that the Sith were not pure evil but merely approached the Force in a different and less restricted way.

But does the Jedi particularly Yoda,Mace Windu, and others know this reason of Dooku's turn to the Dark Side?

Comment: "*“Become unreliable, Dooku has,” Yoda said before Mace could reply. His voice dropped. “Joined the dark side. Lies, deceit, creating mistrust are his ways now.”*" - I suspect that Yoda doesn't care why Dooku turned to the dark side, only that he has.

Comment: Would they ever try to find out? That doesn't seem like something the Jedi would bother with, the effect being more important than the path.

Comment: Do, or do not. There is no why.

Comment: @Valorum , Yoda is count Dooku's master.So it would not make sense for him not to care about his former padawan's fall.Considering that the Jedi are striving to Redemption with love.

Comment: @TheWitchKingofAngmar - There are multiple references to Yoda teaching that *those that have turned to the dark side are irredeemable.*

Comment: How hypocrite Yoda was, then

Comment: @TheWitchKingofAngmar - Well, if something hasn't happened in a thousand years, it's probably not gonna happen ever

Answer (score 5):

First to mention that we as readers know about Dooku's motivation mostly from Legends novels like [Darth Plagueis](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Darth_Plagueis_%28novel%29) and [Labyrinth of Evil](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Labyrinth_of_Evil). There is precious little information in Canon.

In SW universe very few people knew Dooku well enough to know why he turned to Dark Side, and their number is even smaller if you count only those that survived Clone War.

Among them **Palpatine** is first. Palpatine probably knew most of Dooku's secrets, including his weakness that seduced him to darkness. But Palpatine also wanted to erase all traces of Sith Grand Plan once it was fulfilled, and to destroy all clues that connected him with Dooku. Therefore, it was highly unlikely Emperor would talk with anybody about dead Count, except ...

**Vader**, who killed the man and took his mantle of Sith apprentice. Was Vader curious about Dooku, and did Palpatine satisfied his curiosity we currently do not know. It is worth of mentioning that Vader did [travel to Dooku's home world of Serenno](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Cleansing_of_Serenno) in order to punish nobles there. This is also part of Legends, but theoretically Vader did have opportunity to learn something from this expedition.

Finnally, there is another group that could have known something about Count and these are [Kaminoans](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Kaminoan/Legends). In Clone Wars TV series Kaminoan cloners communicate with Tyranus in order to keep secret of Protocol 66 and inhibitor chips from Jedi. Did they knew that Tyranus, man who ordered Clone Army, is actually Dooku ? Most likely, because Dooku was after all public face of the CIS. In [Clone Wars S06E02](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Conspiracy), Kaminoans discuss with Tyranus true purpose of inhibitor chips, implying that they did have some info about motivation of their client. What happened to them after the war is unclear in Canon, in Legends they attempt a rebellion against Empire but were quickly put down by Vader.

Could anyone of people mentioned above talk to Jedi ? Palpatine almost certainly not, but Vader after his redemption and reappearance as Anakin's ghost could be potential source of information on many things. As for Kaminoans, it is anyone's guess .

Comment: You should write it as "the Count", to make it more clear that you aren't saying "count" as in "counting".

Comment: @Acccumulation Point taken.